# No matching version found for @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@5.36.1

Tags: npm, create-react-app, typescript-eslint

I am trying to do 'npx create-react-app react-app' and all troubleshooting I have tried so far is receiving the following error:

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@5.36.1.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2022-08-30T16_43_36_865Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting react-app/ from /Users/user/Malauzai/React-Practice/Ex_Files_React_js_EssT/Exercise Files/Ch04/04_01/start
Done.
```

From digging around a bit on stackoverflow and other sites, I see previous similar examples of failures that were due to a package from the author being bad. I see from the package's npmjs.com page that this latest version was just released 2 hrs ago or so. My guess is that there's an issue in this package causing my failures. At this point I do not see an issue about this on the package's site (https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues). I was not having this or any issues when running create-react-app as of yesterday.

I tried changing nvm version to 16.17.0 (LTS at this time), 16.14.0 and 14.18.1 in hopes that one of these would help pull in a previous version of the @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree library. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling create-react-app globally, restarting my system and running the script in different directories to see if perhaps something was corrupted. To this point, none of these things has helped.

So I would like to ask: What other things would others suggest to perhaps address this issue or work around it in the mean time while a fix is issued?

Answer (score 1):

It appears my suspicion is confirmed. NPM must have noticed the issue and fixed via rolling back the version of the affected package. After finally being able to run 'npx create-react-app react-app' successfully, I looked into the node_mudules installed with the project.

By listing out installed node_modules via 'npm ls @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree' command I see that version 5.36.0 is nested under the react-scripts package. The installs now complete and all is well. Attached below is the dependency tree showing what I just mentioned.

```
└─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
  └─┬ eslint-config-react-app@7.0.1
    ├─┬ @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.36.0
    │ ├─┬ @typescript-eslint/type-utils@5.36.0
    │ │ └── @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@5.36.0 
    │ └─┬ @typescript-eslint/utils@5.36.0
    │   └── @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@5.36.0  deduped
```

Answer (score 1):

The npm was using its default .npmrc registry. Delete your `.npmrc` file from `c:\Users\<username>\` and try again.